How to read prefix.wfc_r1 file from quantum espresso?
I have generated a file named prefix.wfc_r1 using wfck2r.x .I want to get the real space eigenvalues and eigenvectors and possibly plot them. I tried to use the octave file generated but it has 5 dimensions and hard to understand.
Please help
